# Google search results shows other domains hosted with same IP address

Tags: dns, web-search, google-search-platform

I have a small reseller web hosting account and have many other domains sharing the same IP address.

The problem is, when I google search my domain name, I find other domains with same IP address showing in my search result.

For example, if my domain name is greenapples.com, the search will display:

- **Fresh Green Apples**
- Buy green apples today.
- www.greenapples.com

- **Fresh Green Apples**
- Buy green apples today.
- www.anotherdomainwithsameip.com      <----??

When I click on the "another domain", it shows my website though without my domain.

I have tried to block with robots.txt and has not worked.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: That does look like one misconfigured hosting. What would now be your desired behavior when someone tries "another domain", redirect them to your domain, show 404 error, or something else?